# DirectX render 2D image

Tags: directx, directx-11

I want to simply render a 2D image to the window. After hours of digging into DirectX, still can't find a way to do it. Can I simply load the image into buffer then let swapchain to display this buffer of image?

Comment: What have you tried? What exact problem do you face? The easiest is to use Direct2D over DirectX. There's an example of loading a bitmap in official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/how-to-draw-a-bitmap

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.swapchainpanel?view=winrt-22621 That should do it for c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **SimpleTexture** sample on GitHub demonstrates exactly this scenario for C++.

- [DX11 Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/main/PCSamples/IntroGraphics/SimpleTexturePC)
- [DX11 UWP](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/main/UWPSamples/IntroGraphics/SimpleTextureUWP)
- [DX12 Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/main/PCSamples/IntroGraphics/SimpleTexturePC12)
- [DX12 UWP](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/main/UWPSamples/IntroGraphics/SimpleTextureUWP12)

> As you are new to DirectX, you may also want to look at the *DirectX Tool Kit* for [DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Sprites-and-textures) / [DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Sprites-and-textures) which provides a very simple to use **SpriteBatch** class.